# Why do I get the error "Bad name after test3'" when I try to use nested given/when statements?

Tags: perl, switch-statement

Using Perl v5.10 I am attempting to nest `given` statements - i.e. call a `given` statement when one of the initial `when` cases are met. Example:

```
my $value = "test3";
my $subvalue = "subtest2";
my $content .= "\nvalue:";

given($value) {
    when ('test1') { $content .= "test1" }
    when ('test2 ) { $content .= "test2" }
    when ('test3') {
        given($subvalue) {
            when ('subtest1') { $content .= "subtest1" }
            when ('subtest2') { $content .= "subtest2" }
            when ('subtest3') { $content .= "subtest3" }
            when ('subtest4') { $content .= "subtest4" }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Bad name after test3' at ....

Is it possible to nest `given` statements in Perl v5.10?

Comment: Just FYI, [`given`/`when` are experimental](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when): "...the 'switch' feature is considered highly experimental; it is subject to change with little notice. In particular, `when` has tricky behaviours that are expected to change to become less tricky in the future. Do not rely upon its current (mis)implementation. Before Perl 5.18, `given` also had tricky behaviours that you should still beware of if your code must run on older versions of Perl."

Comment: At first, I was going to say that you should delete your question since it was caused by a typo and isn't likely to help future visitors. But the error `Bad name after...` isn't incredibly helpful and it's not too far-fetched that someone else could make the same mistake. Hmm...

Comment: Apparently I can't delete it anyway because it has answers. I've voted to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error, I suspect the code you are running is not the code you are showing us, and there is somewhere a missing end-`'`.  Perl is seeing the `'` before test3 as a closing quote and `test3'` as the beginning of a qualified identifier (`'` is the old perl4 way to say `::`) but without the rest of the identifier.

```
$ echo 'Bad name after '|splain
Bad name after  (#1)
    (F) You started to name a symbol by using a package prefix, and then
    didn't finish the symbol.  In particular, you can't interpolate outside
    of quotes, so

        $var = 'myvar';
        $sym = mypack::$var;

    is not the same as

        $var = 'myvar';
        $sym = "mypack::$var";
```

splain/use diagnostics/perldoc perldiag can be your friend in deciphering odd errors.

Comment: How to make call? next code does not work `"mypack::$var"( 1, 'a' )`

Comment: @EugenKonkov you want to call a sub whose name is in $var and that is in the mypack package?  `&{"mypack::$var"}( 1, 'a' )`.  or `mypack::->$var( 1, 'a' )` if you want to call it as a class method

Comment: Thank you. But is there a typo: `::->`?

Comment: @EugenKonkov no, that makes it use the package "mypack" even if there is a sub named mypack.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce. I tried with a number of version, including 5.10.1.

```
$ cat a.pl
use feature qw( switch );
no if $] >= 5.018, warnings => qw( experimental::smartmatch );

my $value = "test3";
my $subvalue = "subtest2";
my $content .= "\nvalue:";

given($value) {
    when ('test1') { $content .= "test1" }
    when ('test2') { $content .= "test2" }
    when ('test3') {
        given($subvalue) {
            when ('subtest1') { $content .= "subtest1" }
            when ('subtest2') { $content .= "subtest2" }
            when ('subtest3') { $content .= "subtest3" }
            when ('subtest4') { $content .= "subtest4" }
        }
    }
}

$ perl -c a.pl
a.pl syntax OK
```

The error you gave does had to do with qualified package names, but the code you provided doesn't contain any `:`. I don't believe the code you posted generates the error you claim it does.

Comment: Based on the information at [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements), there are definitely some differences between versions v5.10.1 and v5.14. So maybe this isn't supported in the earlier version...

Comment: Pretty sure there aren't. There were some changes between 5.10.0 and 5.10.1 in the matching rules. But that's it (so far). In the middle of installing 5.10.1, so we'll find out shortly.

Comment: Always run the code you actually post

Answer (score 0):

You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program

Your code works fine for me. This is running on Perl v5.10.1 on Windows

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use feature qw/ switch say /;
no warnings 'experimental';

my $value    = "test3";
my $subvalue = "subtest2";
my $content  = "\nvalue:";

given ($value) {
    when ('test1') { $content .= "test1" }
    when ('test2') { $content .= "test2" }
    when ('test3') {
        given ($subvalue) {
            when ('subtest1') { $content .= "subtest1" }
            when ('subtest2') { $content .= "subtest2" }
            when ('subtest3') { $content .= "subtest3" }
            when ('subtest4') { $content .= "subtest4" }
        }
    }
}

say $content;
```

### output

```
value:subtest2
```

Comment: I am using strict and warnings. The code I provided is just a modified snipit.